# Stationarity and Unit Root panel tests in my panel data model

Tags: r, panel-data

I want to study the stationarity and unit root of my panel data, but the tests the internet/books suggest don't work on my data (like punitroot: ips, llc...). A common error I get is this:

```
llc_test_std <- punitroot(data_3$y, test = "llc", lags = "AIC")
Error in punitroot(data_3$y$value, test = "llc", lags = "AIC") : 
  unused arguments (test = "llc", lags = "AIC").
```

I have tried to standardize the data before, but without success. Can you help me? Should I correct my R version (which is 4.2.3)? Or is the problem in my data?

I'm trying to verify that my data is stationary so I can proceed with estimating ols without a problem. For if they are not stationary I should apply the first difference (or another method)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.

Comment: `punitroot` seemt to be the function from the unreleased (in the sense of CRAN availability) package `punitroot`. You may want to try panel unit root tests in a released package such as `plm`, functions `purtest`, `ciptstest`, and `phansitest`; see also the package's vignett with a section about panel unit root testing: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/A_plmPackage.html